# Passing a model to another view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

All,

I'm new to MVC and therefore learning it as I go along by working on a new project. I have some simple functionality I would like to achieve but don't know if I'm doing it the correct way - the current approach results in a runtime error - a description of the problem is below.

I'm trying to create some password reset functionality. To reset a password, I'm going to get the user to enter their username and e-mail on one view. Then on a second view I'm going to display their password reset question and get them to enter their password reset answer. The second view will also display their username, so I need to pass the entered username from view one into view two. I have the following two models so far:

```
public class ResetPasswordModelStepOne
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class ResetPasswordModelStepTwo
{
    public ResetPasswordModelStepOne StepOneModel { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Question")]
    public string ResetQuestion { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Answer")]
    public string ResetAnswer { get; set; }
}
```

Notice that the second model also has a property to store the step one model, this is so that on the second view, I can access and display the users username in a message like "Hi {Username}, to reset your password, please answer your password reset question.". I have created strongly typed views for both the above models and have the following actions.

```
    public ActionResult PasswordResetStepOne()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PasswordResetStepOne(ResetPasswordModelStepOne stepOneModel)
    {
        //Imagine i'm validating that the user exists here and then retrieving
        //their secret question from a repository
        var userSecretQuestion = "What is your favourite color?";

        return PasswordResetStepTwo(new ResetPasswordModelStepTwo { StepOneModel = stepOneModel, ResetQuestion = userSecretQuestion });
    }

    public ActionResult PasswordResetStepTwo(ResetPasswordModelStepTwo stepTwoModel)
    {
        return View(stepTwoModel);
    }
```

The problem I'm having with this approach is that when the user enters their username and email on the first step view, I then call the "PasswordResetStepTwo" action which returns the strongly typed view for ResetPasswordModelStepTwo - this results in the following runtime error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'MvcCrossPageModel.Models.ResetPasswordModelStepTwo', but this
>   dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'MvcCrossPageModel.Models.ResetPasswordModelStepOne'.

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong here? Is there a better way to achieve this in one view with one model? Am I doing this correctly by creating "step one" and "step two" models? Ideally I'd like to have a single view, the user enters their username and email - then the same view is returned prompting them for their secret question/

Comment: What is the VIewModel for the PasswordResetSteptTwo view?

Comment: The model for the step two view is ResetPasswordModelStepTwo. I received a comment from another guy on here which suggested using RedirectToAction in PasswordResetStepOne POST and using TempData to pass the username and email from step one to step two. I've done it this way and it is working great - although I'm still not sure if it makes sense to have two seperate views for this simple functionality, can't it be achieved in MVC with just one view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
every strongly typed views has one model. But you have two ways.
Razor syntax
1.Use this view.
    @model dynamic
    <div>
    any html
    @(using Html.BeginForm()){
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    <button type="submit">save</button>
    }
    </div>

2. Use two views

public ActionResult PasswordResetStepOne()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PasswordResetStepOne(ResetPasswordModelStepOne stepOneModel)
    {
        //Imagine i'm validating that the user exists here and then retrieving
        //their secret question from a repository
        var userSecretQuestion = "What is your favourite color?";

        return PasswordResetStepTwo(new ResetPasswordModelStepTwo { StepOneModel = stepOneModel, ResetQuestion = userSecretQuestion });
    }

    public ActionResult PasswordResetStepTwo(ResetPasswordModelStepTwo stepTwoModel)
    {
        return View("NextViewName",stepTwoModel);
    }
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't know you could have @model dynamic - I'll try it this way and get back to you user1304836 - unfortunately I am now out of the house so will give it a try when I get home. This looks promising though, thanks.

Comment: Thanks - I went for the dynamic model option